# I want my discord bot to respond if a specific message is coming from a specific user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The best solution I've managed to find so far is to check the user id.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if(message.author == client.user):  #if message is coming from the bot itself
        return

    
    if(message.author.id == 103001222035981612 and message.content.startswith == 'Yo'):
            await message.channel.send('Hello {}'.format(message.author.name))
    
        
    #await message.channel.send(message.content)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

What ends up happening is the bot responds regardless of what it is I say, which is not what I want it to do. I've tried some other ways of doing it but none of them were of any help. I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure to add this at the very end**

```
*await client.process_commands(message)*
```

**Example:**

```
@client.event   
async def on_message(message): 
 
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
     await message.channel.send("hey!")
  await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: That was the solution thanks, but what does that line of code do exactly?

Comment: this makes it so the bot knows to stop, and only respond to what you want the on_message part reacts to.

Comment: Ok! just make sure to ask good questions and make sure your statement is clear!

Comment: Was this a bad question or not clear enough?

Comment: yes. This is your first question but you forgot some part of your code at the front and beginning make sure to 
``` 
and at the end
 ```
they cant be on the same like only once before and after! This will make sure you get all the code in the ` part 
I did submit a edit request and when it gets verified you will see how its supposed to be shown!